# python selenium choose random firefox profile

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

In my script folder I have copied my firefox profiles folders

My code

```
#Creating profile for browser
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('.\profiles\profile1')
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", user_agent)
profile.update_preferences()
```

What I would like to do is

```
#Creating profile for browser
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('.\profiles\random_profile_from_profiles_folder')
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", user_agent)
profile.update_preferences()
```

Comment: `p = random.choice(ffp1_list)` : p is now a line randomly chosen from your file. Use that.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre please review my updated question. And if you can inform me of how I code the  script to choose the Random profile from my profiles folder. Thanks

Comment: @daniel.kahlenberg can you help anwser? im also curious as to when you mentioned adding xvfb for headless interaction can you run multiple firefox browser profiles through the xvfb? I am forced to use pyautogui for adobe interactions. Unfortunately pyauto gui interacts on like an OS level. Do you know if its possible or another way to interact with adobe inside xvfb. This way I can run my script and still interact with my computer without worrying about pyautogui not interacting as its suppose to. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only modification I perform is 1) list profiles directory, 2) filter to keep only directories 3) apply random on the list

I hope it's what you want:

```
import os,random

profile_dir="profiles"

# pick a directory
randdir = random.choice(list(filter(os.path.isdir,os.listdir(profile_dir))))

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(os.path.join(profile_dir,randdir))
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", user_agent)
profile.update_preferences()
```